# Find All Sunday dates between two different input fields Mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains: Id, Name, Startdate, Enddate. I would like to Find All Sunday dates between Startdate and Enddate.

Table Mysqli

| ID | Name | Startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | robert | 01-01-2024 | 31-01-2024 |
| 2 | ann | 13-01-2024 | 20-01-2024 |
| 3 | ken | 20-01-2024 | 25-01-2024 |
| 4 | marco | 20-01-2024 | 30-01-2024 |

Output Result Expected to take all sundays of the persons in the date range.

| Name | Sundays |
| --- | --- |
| robert | 07-01-2024 |
| robert | 14-01-2024 |
| robert | 21-01-2024 |
| robert | 28-01-2024 |
| ann | 14-01-2024 |
| ken | 21-01-2024 |
| marco | 21-01-2024 |
| marco | 28-01-2024 |

Comment: please show the rows and columns you want returned, including what you want returned if there are no sundays in the range

Comment: please correct your typos, what date is "30-02-204" even supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using a similar approach to the other answers, but it starts by getting the first Sunday and then incrementing by week, instead of day.

MySQL 5.5

```sql
SELECT tbl.name AS Name, d.sun_date AS Sundays
FROM tbl
JOIN (
    SELECT vars.first_sunday + INTERVAL (@row := @row + 1) - 1 WEEK AS sun_date
    FROM information_schema.columns
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            MIN(startdate) + INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK(MIN(startdate)) = 1, 0, 8 - DAYOFWEEK(MIN(startdate))) DAY AS first_sunday,
            MIN(startdate) AS min_start,
            MAX(enddate) AS max_end,
            @row := 0
        FROM tbl
    ) vars
    WHERE @row <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, vars.min_start, vars.max_end)
) d ON d.sun_date BETWEEN tbl.startdate AND tbl.enddate
ORDER BY tbl.startdate, tbl.name, d.sun_date;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7fdmPZnW).

---

MySQL 8+

This query does all the work in the rCTE:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, startdate, enddate,
        startdate + INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK(startdate) = 1, 0, 8 - DAYOFWEEK(startdate)) DAY AS sun_date
    FROM tbl

    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT id, name, startdate, enddate,
        sun_date + INTERVAL 1 WEEK AS sun_date
    FROM cte
    WHERE sun_date + INTERVAL 1 WEEK <= enddate
)
SELECT name AS Name, sun_date AS Sundays
FROM cte
WHERE sun_date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
ORDER BY startdate, sun_date;
```

Another MySQL 8+ variant

This query uses the rCTE to build the full set of Sundays between the minimum startdate and the maximum enddate, and then joins to the source data:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte (Sundays, max_end) AS (
    SELECT
        MIN(startdate) + INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK(MIN(startdate)) = 1, 0, 8 - DAYOFWEEK(MIN(startdate))) DAY,
        MAX(enddate)
    FROM tbl

    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT Sundays + INTERVAL 1 WEEK, max_end
    FROM cte
    WHERE Sundays + INTERVAL 1 WEEK <= max_end
)
SELECT tbl.name AS Name, cte.Sundays
FROM cte
JOIN tbl ON cte.Sundays BETWEEN tbl.startdate AND tbl.enddate
ORDER BY tbl.startdate, cte.Sundays;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Gu8VZUy).

All three of these queries output:

| Name | Sundays |
| --- | --- |
| robert | 2024-01-07 |
| robert | 2024-01-14 |
| robert | 2024-01-21 |
| robert | 2024-01-28 |
| ann | 2024-01-14 |
| ken | 2024-01-21 |
| marco | 2024-01-21 |
| marco | 2024-01-28 |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want one row per original row and a comma separated list of dates, this would be:

```
with recursive date_range as (
   select id, name, startdate, enddate,
     case when startdate <= enddate then startdate end date_in_range
   from mystery_table_name
   
   union all
   
   select id,name,startdate,enddate,date_in_range + interval 1 day
   from date_range
   where date_in_range < enddate
)
select id, name, startdate, enddate,
  group_concat(case when dayofweek(date_in_range)=1 then date_in_range end order by date_in_range) sundays
from date_range
group by id, name, startdate, enddate
order by id, name, startdate, enddate
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QI7MFrAG)

Comment: I edited the question with table view. Hope it is more clear now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH recursive dates AS (
  SELECT MIN(Startdate) as d FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(d,INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM dates WHERE d <= (SELECT MAX(enddate) FROM mytable)
)
SELECT m.Name, d.d
FROM dates d
JOIN mytable m ON d.d BETWEEN m.Startdate and m.enddate
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(d) = 1
ORDER BY d.d;
```

- The CTE is creating a temporary result containing all datum from the lowest startdate until the last enddate.
- Then an JOIN is done against the input
- using a WHERE to filter only Sundays

output:

| Name | d |
| --- | --- |
| robert | 2024-01-07 |
| robert | 2024-01-14 |
| ann | 2024-01-14 |
| robert | 2024-01-21 |
| ken | 2024-01-21 |
| marco | 2024-01-21 |
| robert | 2024-01-28 |
| marco | 2024-01-28 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/hab8fd61)

EDIT: The same, but for MySQL5

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dates(d DATE);
SELECT @Rmin := MIN(Startdate) FROM mytable;
SELECT @Rmax := MAX(enddate) FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO dates VALUES (@Rmin);

SET @row := 0;
INSERT INTO dates
SELECT DATE_ADD(@Rmin,  INTERVAL @row:=@row+1 DAY)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE @row <= datediff(@Rmax,@Rmin)-1;

SELECT m.Name, d.d
FROM dates d
JOIN mytable m ON d.d BETWEEN m.Startdate and m.enddate
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(d) = 1
ORDER BY d.d;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/sEv9mmq4)

Comment: @lukk this is working perfectly fine with mysql 8 but my server version is MySQL: 5.5.5 and showing recursive error

Comment: @backupfiles: The are some examples on stackoverflow on how to convert a CTE to Mysql5 compatible solution, I did that for you ....